# socat не может захватить порт с первого раза

Tags: linux, сокет, systemd

Такой скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

PORT=$(readlink -f $1)
while true; do
    socat TCP-LISTEN:5555 $PORT,b115200,raw,echo=0 || sleep 1;
done;
```

Запускаю службой:

```
[Unit]
Description=Com over TCP service %i
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=dialout
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/CoT/cot.sh %i
TimeoutSec=300
WorkingDirectory=/dev/serial/by-id


[Install]
Alias=multi-user.target.wants/cot@%i.service
```

10 секунд после старта служба не может забиндить порт. Но порт свободен при этом.

```
root@comp# systemctl status cot@usb-serial-if00.service
● cot@usb-serial-if00.service - Com over TCP service usb-serial-if00
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cot@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-07-04 12:58:14 MSK; 23s ago
 Main PID: 2273 (cot.sh)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-cot.slice/cot@usb-serial-if00.service
           ├─2273 /bin/bash /opt/CoT/cot.sh usb-serial-if00
           └─2332 socat TCP-LISTEN:5555 /dev/ttyACM0,b115200,raw,echo=0

июл 04 12:58:23 comp cot.sh[2273]: 2018/07/04 12:58:23 socat[2296] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:5555}, 16): Address already in use
июл 04 12:58:24 comp cot.sh[2273]: 2018/07/04 12:58:24 socat[2298] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:5555}, 16): Address already in use
июл 04 12:58:25 comp cot.sh[2273]: 2018/07/04 12:58:25 socat[2300] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:5555}, 16): Address already in use
июл 04 12:58:26 comp cot.sh[2273]: 2018/07/04 12:58:26 socat[2304] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:5555}, 16): Address already in use
июл 04 12:58:27 comp cot.sh[2273]: 2018/07/04 12:58:27 socat[2306] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:5555}, 16): Address already in use
июл 04 12:58:28 comp cot.sh[2273]: 2018/07/04 12:58:28 socat[2308] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:5555}, 16): Address already in use
июл 04 12:58:29 comp cot.sh[2273]: 2018/07/04 12:58:29 socat[2312] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:5555}, 16): Address already in use
июл 04 12:58:30 comp cot.sh[2273]: 2018/07/04 12:58:30 socat[2314] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:5555}, 16): Address already in use
июл 04 12:58:31 comp cot.sh[2273]: 2018/07/04 12:58:31 socat[2320] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:5555}, 16): Address already in use
июл 04 12:58:32 comp cot.sh[2273]: 2018/07/04 12:58:32 socat[2326] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:5555}, 16): Address already in use
```

После того как подключится работает нормально и переподключается стабильно.

Comment: Судя по комментариям в дампах, может проще поставить и настроить `ser2net`?

Comment: ser2net не заработал с первой попытки с приложением, хотя если телнетом пробовать - вроде норм. вопрос то почему порт не открывается сразу

Comment: и еще мне наверное надо открывать компорт по запросу с тцп, а не держать его.

Comment: *ser2net* так и делает. Вы пробовали *raw* режим там настроить?

Comment: пробовал какраз рав. клиент виснет на вводе-выводе.
устройства принтер через /dev/usb/lp0 и касса через cdc_serial. ser2net слишком сериальный плохо работает с портами без контроля потока

Comment: Для принтера там специальный *rawlp*. Остальное надо смотреть по ситуации. (А *socat* таки работает?)

Comment: работает хорошо после 10 секунд